Duplicate declaration in scheme using ENT ORM in GO
Using Go and ent ORM, I am creating a many-to-many relationship in which a source spec can have many tags, and the same tags can be used in any source spec.
Initially, I named my model tag SourceSpecTag and generated the wrong relation one to many from source spec to source spec tags. Then I modified the edges to be many to many (see code fragment), but any time I run the go generate, I get the error shown below. Even when I renamed the SourceSpecTag struct to Tag now,  my schema is being generated with duplicate declarations for columns and the table.
I have deleted all files and renamed reference names, but I still keep having this issue and don't see any duplication. I appreciate any help trying to figure out this issue. Thank you.
What is interesting for me is that even after renaming the model, it still generates a schema with SourceSpecTagsTable instead TagsTable
that
Error
{"level":"fatal","error":"entc/load: # github.com/portable-io/portable/ent/migrate\nmigrate/schema.go:679:2: SourceSpecTagsColumns redeclared in this block\n\tmigrate/schema.go:508:2: other declaration of SourceSpecTagsColumns\nmigrate/schema.go:684:2: SourceSpecTagsTable redeclared in this block\n\tmigrate/schema.go:513:2: other declaration of SourceSpecTagsTable\n","time":"2024-07-24T09:26:12-04:00","message":"running ent codegen"}

Fragment wrong generated schema.go
    // SourceSpecTagsColumns holds the columns for the "source_spec_tags" table.
    SourceSpecTagsColumns = []*schema.Column{
        {Name: "id", Type: field.TypeInt, Increment: true},
        {Name: "tag", Type: field.TypeString, Unique: true},
    }
    // SourceSpecTagsTable holds the schema information for the "source_spec_tags" table.
    SourceSpecTagsTable = &schema.Table{
        Name:       "source_spec_tags",
        Columns:    SourceSpecTagsColumns,
        PrimaryKey: []*schema.Column{SourceSpecTagsColumns[0]},
    }

}
    // SourceSpecTagsColumns holds the columns for the "source_spec_tags" table.
    SourceSpecTagsColumns = []*schema.Column{
        {Name: "source_spec_id", Type: field.TypeInt},
        {Name: "source_spec_tag_id", Type: field.TypeInt},
    }
    // SourceSpecTagsTable holds the schema information for the "source_spec_tags" table.
    SourceSpecTagsTable = &schema.Table{
        Name:       "source_spec_tags",
        Columns:    SourceSpecTagsColumns,
        PrimaryKey: []*schema.Column{SourceSpecTagsColumns[0], SourceSpecTagsColumns[1]},
        ForeignKeys: []*schema.ForeignKey{
            {
                Symbol:     "source_spec_tags_source_spec_id",
                Columns:    []*schema.Column{SourceSpecTagsColumns[0]},
                RefColumns: []*schema.Column{SourceSpecsColumns[0]},
                OnDelete:   schema.Cascade,
            },
            {
                Symbol:     "source_spec_tags_source_spec_tag_id",
                Columns:    []*schema.Column{SourceSpecTagsColumns[1]},
                RefColumns: []*schema.Column{SourceSpecTagsColumns[0]},
                OnDelete:   schema.Cascade,
            },
        },
    }

Entities
package model

// SourceSpec holds the schema definition for the SourceSpec entity.
type SourceSpec struct {
    ent.Schema
}

// Fields of the SourceSpec.
func (SourceSpec) Fields() []ent.Field {
    return []ent.Field{
        ....
}

// Mixin of the SourceSpec.
func (SourceSpec) Mixin() []ent.Mixin {
    return []ent.Mixin{
        AuditTimestampsMixin{},
        MutationMixin{},
    }
}
package model


// Tag holds the schema definition for the Tag entity.
type Tag struct {
    ent.Schema
}

// Fields of the Tag.
func (Tag) Fields() []ent.Field {
    return []ent.Field{
        field.String("tag").
            Unique().
            NotEmpty().
            StructTag(`yaml:"tag" json:"tag,omitempty"`),
    }
}

// Edges of the SourceSpecTag.
func (Tag) Edges() []ent.Edge {
    return []ent.Edge{
        edge.From("source_specs", SourceSpec.Type).
            Ref("tags"),
    }
}

I tried deleting ent dir content, renaming entity, changing edge ref names modifying the schema after generation running, and try to generate again but still keep having the same issue
